# Reading lines from stdin into 2d array in C without knowing length of lines

Tags: c, stdin

I want to read lines from stdin with variable length until the end of input. The example input would be something like this:

```
#.###############
#...#...........#
#.###.#####.#.###
#...........#...#
###############.#
```

but with various lengths of rows and columns.

What is the best way to read it into 2d array except for reading it as chars?

Comment: If you don't know the number of lines, or the length of each line, then no you really don't have much choice than to read character by character and check for newline.

Comment: Thanks...I thought so...but I got an assignement and the automatic testing wont take my solution and I was adviced that I should read the whole lines instead of chars :(

Comment: While you don't know the exact length of each line, is there some upper limit to the lengths? Unless it's tens of thousands of characters, then you could just have a large array and use `fgets`. Or if you're on a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) then you could use `getline` as [answered by Andew Henle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40931560/440558).

Comment: Tone of dupes here: http://www.google.com/search?q=reading+unknown+number+of+lines+with+unknown+length+from+file+in+c+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40917629/971127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running on a POSIX-compliant system, you can use [the `getline()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) to read lines of almost arbitrary length (only limited by available memory).  Something like this should work:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t bytes = 0UL;

for ( int ii = 0;; ii++ )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = getline( &line, &bytes, stdin );
    if ( bytesRead <= 0L )
    {
        break;
    }

    lineArray[ ii ] = strdup( line );
}

free( line );
```

You'll have to add error checking and take care of `lineArray` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *buff = malloc(1024 * 100); // 100K should be plenty, tweak as desired.
char *maze = 0;
int width = 0, 
int height = 0;    

FILE *fp = fopen(input.txt, "r");
fgets(buff, 1024 * 100, fp);
if(!strchr(buff, '\n'))
   goto failed_sanity_test;
striptrailingwhitespace(buff);
if(height == 0)
   width = strlen(buff);
/* sanity-test width ? */
else
   if(strlen(buff) != width)
       goto ragged_edge_maze;
temp = realloc(maze, width * (height + 1));
if(!temp) 
  goto out_of_memory;
maze = temp;
memcpy(maze + height * width, buff, width);
height++;
```

Its fiddly in C in comparison to many other langues, but at least you have full control of the error conditions.